# How to get out unallocated space out from an extended ext4 partition

Tags: gparted, partitioning, resize

I have an extended partition /dev/sda2. It has many partitions of my ubuntu.
I want to resized them and get the unallocated space out for a windwos install.

But Whenever I try to do this in gparted live, It says you can resize on right click but when I try to do it, it dosen't happens. It says max and min space are equal.

Please help me. Before is its screenshot.

[image: GParted screenshot on my Ubuntu]

Comment: It’s not a great idea to install Windows after Ubuntu. You might find the best way to achieve what you want is back-up your Ubuntu data, wipe the disk, install Windows and then Ubuntu. When you try to resize sda2 have you moved the other partitions within it? I think you need to move them all to the left and then shrink sda2

Comment: I have prepared for the consequences of a windows install after ubuntu and shall keep that topic aside. I didn't understand of you moving the partitions to the left?

Comment: You can reduce the size of the extended partition only if the unallocated space in it is at the right or left end of the extended partition, so you will have to move one or more of the logical partitions first.

Comment: So, how do we move it? Can you provide detailed explaination in an answer

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what I think you want to do take the following steps after backing up any important data:

1. Boot gparted live (you cannot move sda9 while it is mounted by your Ubuntu install)
2. Move sda5 so that it is adjacent to sda8
3. repeat for sda6 so that it is adjacent to sda5
4. likewise for sda9, then sda7, then sda10. At this point all the unallocated space should be at the right hand end of sda8
5. Next you should now be able to shrink sda8 so it contains no unallocated space
6. Finally you should be able to create a fourth primary partition in the unallocated space for your Windows install.

At each step select the partition you are working on, right click, and use the Resize/Move option. You have to click the green tick icon to apply what you have specified using the Resize/Move option. You can specify more than one change before applying it but I would recommend doing it step by step.

If this is not detailed enough I suggest searching youtube for "Gparted Move". you will get plenty of videos returned that will demonstrate Gparted

Comment: Thanks for your sugesstion. Will try it as soon as possible